# Continuity of $x^2$ over $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Where $\infty ^2 = -\infty ^2 = \infty$ and the metric $\rho(x,y) = |\arctan(x) -\arctan(y)|$.

My approach: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a $\delta_1$ such that $|\arctan(x^2) -\arctan(y^2)| < \epsilon$ when $|x^2-y^2| <\delta_1$. Then by usual continuity of $x^2$, we have there exists a $\delta_2$ such that $|x-y|<\delta_2$ implies $|x^2-y^2| <\delta_1$. Now if we choose $\epsilon$ sufficiently small then we will have $y\in\mathbb{R}$ too. Then by the continuity of $\tan$ for numbers in $(-\pi/2,\pi,2)$, we have that there exists a $\delta_3$ such that $|\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)| < \delta_3$ implies $|x-y|<\delta_2$. Which shows the result for when $x\in \mathbb{R}$. And when $x\notin \mathbb{R}$, the approach is basically the same.

My question is whether this makes sense? This seems like a lot of work, is there an easier way to show this? I thought about using the topological version of continuity but it wasn't clear how to show that open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are open in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: You can show that these metrics result in the same topologies by noting that the sets of the form $[-\infty,a)$, $(a,\infty]$, and $(a,b)$ form a base (or "basis" depending on your terminology) for either topology.  I think it follows that functions continuous wrt one metric are continuous wrt the other.

Answer (score 0):

Define a map $f:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ by $f(\pm \pi/2)=\pm\infty$ and $f(x)=\tan x$ for interior $x$. By definition of the metric on $\overline{\mathbb R}$, $f$ is an isometric bijection. Thus, it preserves all metric properties of the spaces under consideration. A function $g : \overline{\mathbb R}\to \overline{\mathbb R}$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}\circ g\circ f$ is continuous on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ in the usual metric. With $g(x)=x^2$ we get
$$f^{-1}\circ g\circ f(x) = \begin{cases}\arctan \tan^2 x,\quad &|x|<\pi/2 \\ \pi/2,\quad &|x|=\pi/2\end{cases}$$
To show continuity, we only need to check that $\arctan \tan^2 x\to \pi/2$ as $x\to\pm \pi/2$, which is easy.